# Cordova windows : identify the launched URI

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have 2 windows apps in which one is native and one is cordova windows app.
user will be having some set of navigations from windows native app which would invoke the respective page in cordova app depending up on the URI invoked from native app.

i am actually new to cordova. The similar thing in native i should be able to handle using below code

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
        {
            var _args = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
            argValues.Add(_args.Uri.ToString());

            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;


            if (rootFrame == null)
            {

                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }

            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), argValues);
            }
            Window.Current.Activate();

            // TODO: Handle URI activation
            // The received URI is eventArgs.Uri.AbsoluteUri
        }
    }
```

The above app lifecycle event is been added to Application class(app.xaml). But didn't saw similar application class in cordova window app. If application class can be added to Cordova I would like to develop a similar plugin like [cordova-webintent https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent)

I saw one corodva windows plugin but it supports only for win8 Phone 
[cordova-urlhandler-plugin](https://github.com/hypery2k/cordova-urlhandler-plugin)